# In SQL, should we first check if user has permissions and then assign it or simply run the grant permission query. Which query is less costly?

Tags: sql-server

Some SQL queries will run repeatedly. The main purpose of those queries is to give SQL user `Alter` permission on a table and `Execute` permission on a stored procedure.

```
GRANT ALTER ON Table TO User;
GRANT Execute ON [dbo].Sp_StoredProcedure TO User;
```

Is it better to directly run grant queries, or first check if user has those permissions? If it has then ignore else run the grant queries. I find the second type of query to be more costly as it involves joining many tables.

Is this assumption right. Any inputs or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're running code to change permissions on a database often enough that performance is a concern, you've taken a wrong turn somewhere long before you reached this point.

Comment: Why would this matter?

Comment: One typically grants permissions as part of a database deployment along with schema changes. This is a one-time task, not something that should be done repeatedly.

Comment: These SQL statements have been specified in the release pipeline which might run multiple times. The permissions granted to user don't change. The thing is if the release pipeline runs again then what is a better approach. Just grant permissions or first check and then grant. Its like some optimization thing which kind of striked mind. Not sure how much it helps though.

Comment: Unless the deployment runs multiple times per minute, this shouldn't matter. The real problem is security because the script doesn't *remove* obsolete grants. You may want to remove a permission without explicitly denying it.

Comment: @Riya, IMHO, it is premature optimization to avoid rerunning these idempotent statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer - grant/deny/revoke statements are idempotent. That is, you can run them more than once and, regardless of the initial state, the operation that you asked for will be performed without error (assuming you have the permission to do so).

But, as others have said in the comments, the speed at which such GDR statements run is probably not the long pole in whatever you're trying to do.